# Code Field in Java

Tags: java, jtextarea, jformattedtextfield, rich-snippets

I trying to develop a java application to save *my snippets*. I want to copy codes from anywhere (like *stackoverflow*, *netbeans*, *Xcode*) and paste them into my application to save them with their formatting to retrieve them in future.
 **How can achieve that?**
 **Is jTextArea supporting formatted texts (Code with colors)?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle JTextArea tutorial:

> If you want the text area to display its text using multiple fonts or other styles, you should use an [editor pane or text pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html). If the displayed text has a limited length and is never edited by the user, use a [label](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).

Which means: no, you can't use a JTextArea to format your code, use  a JEditorPane or its subclass JTextPane ([see this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html))

Comment: I will see the tutorial, thank you very much bro. Now I asking, if there is a way  to save the text with its format in database, and when it wii be retrieved, the text will be formatted as in the first case?

Comment: I think you have to save the text and the format into two different fields.

Comment: And no, you can't retrive it "formatted": you have to teach the component how it has to format your text. Again, see the tutorial (and google a bit before asking questions... ;) ).

Comment: OK my dear, thank you very much :|